# how to change color of boxes in 2D grid of specific cell on click in reactJs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Basically I was trying to make 10*10 grid such that clicking on specific cell by it cell number change all multiple cell color? for example clicking on cell 5 it change all boxes which having multiple of 5 values. For grid I used tailwindcss

[image]

Can anyone please tell that why in my code background color of multiple cells is not changing?

```js
const { useState } = React;

function App() {
  const [fillcolor, setFillcolor] = useState("");
  var items = [];
  for (let i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
    items.push(<div onClick={() => changeColor(i)} className="border border-gray-600 text-center">
      {i}
    </div>)
  }
  function changeColor(index) {
    alert(index);
    setFillcolor("yellow");
    for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
      if ((i + 1) % index === 0) {
        items[i] = <div style={{ backgroundColor: fillcolor }} className="border border-gray-600 text-center">
          {(i + 1)}
        </div>
      }
    }
    console.log(items[0]);
  }
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="container">
        <div className="grid grid-cols-10 grid-rows-10">
          {items}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Keep `Item` as a state, do not handle DOM manipulations yourself if you are using react. Keep things you want to change as states and update them through their dispatchers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are modifying `items` inside your `changeColor` function, which React will never find out (since it's not a state). When React rerenders the component, the variable will be redefined. Instead, I'd recommend storing the highlighted factor. The `fillColor` does not need to change (at least in your code it's always set to 'yellow') and therefore should not be a state.

The following should work:

```
function App() {
  const [selectedIndex, setSelectedIndex] = useState(null);
  const items = [];
  for (let i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
    let style = {};
    if(selectedIndex !== null && i % selectedIndex === 0){
        style = {
            backgroundColor: "yellow"
        };
    }
    items.push(<div onClick={() => changeColor(i)} className="border border-gray-600 text-center" style={style}>
      {i}
    </div>)
  }
  function changeColor(index) {
    // only need to set the state here
    setSelectedIndex(index);
  }
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="container">
        <div className="grid grid-cols-10 grid-rows-10">
          {items}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As @skrrrt said, in React is suggested to not manipulate DOM like you are doing now. Much better use state variables. I suggest you to modify your code in this way:

```js
const { useState } = React;

function App() {
  const [fillcolor, setFillcolor] = useState(new Array(100).fill("white"));  // <-- this is an array of colors to apply to elements

  const numbers = Array.from({length: 100}, (_, i) => i + 1); // <-- this is an array of first 100 numbers from 1 to 100

  const multiplesOf = (numbers, number) => numbers.filter(n => !(n % number));  // <-- this function returns multiple of selected value in numbers array

  function changeColor(index) {
 let result = [...fillcolor];
 let indexToColor = multiplesOf(numbers, index);
 indexToColor.forEach((idx) => result[idx - 1] = "yellow");
 setFillcolor(result);
 
  }

  return (
<div className="App">
  <div className="container">
    <div className="grid grid-cols-10 grid-rows-10">
      {numbers.map((el) => (
         <div style={{ backgroundColor: fillcolor[el - 1] }} onClick={() => changeColor(el)} className="border border-gray-600 text-center">
         {el}
         </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Credits: `multiplesOf` function is taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54193060/javascript-function-for-finding-multiples-of-a-number/); `numbers` fill function is taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3746725/how-to-create-an-array-containing-1-n).